# Will block.coinbase.call{value: _ethAmountToCoinbase}(new bytes(0)) revert if transaction fails?

Tags: solidity, revert-opcode

A similar looking statement `address.call(abi.encodeWithSignature())` will not revert if transaction fails because it is an external call.

So, will `block.coinbase.call{value: _ethAmountToCoinbase}(new bytes(0))` also not revert if transaction fails after that statement?

**CODE:** A solidity function has these 3 lines.

```
address.call(abi.encodeWithSignature()) // statement 1
block.coinbase.call{value: _ethAmountToCoinbase}(new bytes(0)) // statement 2
revert()
```

What will happen to result of statement 1 and statement 2 after the `revert()` statement has been executed?